# PHP confusing Object with Array after parsing JSON data

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

having parsed an object of nested objects and nested arrays PHP is mixing them up. it works well on some objects but not on others

```
  $f = json_decode($jsonObject, true);
```

example of nested objects that php recognises as objects:
[image]

examples of arrays which php recognises as objects in arrays:
[image]

examples of object which php recognises as an arrays:
[image]

if i begin mixing arrays of objects it no longer recognises simple objects, it interprets them as arrays.

how can i get php to fully recognise arrays and objects in JSON,

Comment: Please use text/code, not images

Answer (score 1):

You can turn php objects or arrays into json with `json_encode()`

They will come out as an array or an object depending on whether you set the extra flag when decoding. `json_decode($jsonstr,true)` will return an array, `json_decode($jsonstr)` will return an object.

It doesn't matter whether the data was an object or an array before it went in, it only matters how you decode it.

Your code above will always return an array regardless of whether you encode an object or an array.